# Unexpected character "" while using react native in iOS

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, xcode8

I am in the learning stage for using ReactNative in iOS. So currently i have done all the initial set ups for it and now i am following the tutorial for basic learning.
[React Native](https://kylewbanks.com/blog/react-native-tutorial-part-1-hello-react)

But i am getting the following error.

[image]

The associated .js file code is here

```
// src/ReactCalculator.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
    Text,
    AppRegistry
} from 'react-native';

class ReactCalculator extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Text>Hello, React!</Text>
        )
    }

}

AppRegistry.registerComponent(‘reactTutorialApp’, () => ReactCalculator);
```

Please help me with the situation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent(‘reactTutorialApp’, () => ReactCalculator);
```

should be

```
AppRegistry.registerComponent('reactTutorialApp', () => ReactCalculator);
```

Please note the `‘` and `’`. These are special characters.

Answer (score 2):

For my case, my 'visual studio code' was adding some invisble characters before or after of "", still can't avoid it, but I am pressing back key for remove this invisible characters to avoid the "Unexpected character “” " message

Answer (score 0):

I wondered for a long time what it could be. And it was an invisible symbol. It very rarely happens when you copy and paste a piece of code from a website (in my case it was Slack).

Try deleting the line where the error occurs.